# Sorting list of lists by Min Value Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

Suppose I have the following list of lists:

```
A = [[42, 45], [45, 48], [48, 51], [0, 4], [4, 8]]
```

I need to order the sublists that are within the A list according to the minimum value of each sublist.

Expected Output:

```
A = [[0, 4],[4, 8], [42, 45], [45, 48], [48, 51]]
```

Any suggestions would be welcome !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sorted` with `min` as key.

```
a = [[42, 45], [45, 48], [48, 51], [0, 4], [4, 8]]

output = sorted(a, key=min)

print(output) # [[0, 4], [4, 8], [42, 45], [45, 48], [48, 51]]
```

If you want a non-ambiguous way to break ties, you can use `sorted` itself as key to sort according to the minimum and then the second element.

```
a = [[1, 3], [1, 2]]

output = sorted(a, key=sorted)

print(output)  # [[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Comment: That works, thank you very much!

Comment: Keeping `lexicographical ordering` in mind, i think for this problem `key=min` is redundant! `sorted(a)` should produce the same output!

Comment: @bro-grammer that is only because the sublists are already sorted, but would not if it was not the case.

Comment: If sublist aren't sorted, then adding `key=min` won't sort the sublist. Even in that case `sorted(a)` would be equal to `sorted(a, key=min)`.

Answer (score 2):

By specifying a key named argument to either `sort` or `sorted` you can do this:

```
A = [[42, 45], [45, 48], [48, 51], [0, 4], [4, 8]]

# Creating a new list
B = sorted(A, key = lambda x: min(x))
print(B)

# Operating on the original list
A.sort(key = lambda x: min(x))
print(A)
```

Both output: `[[0, 4], [4, 8], [42, 45], [45, 48], [48, 51]]`

Comment: Isn't `key = lambda x: foo(x)` equivalent to `key = foo`?

Comment: It is.  I would edit it but I see Oliver wrote that, so I'll leave it as is so the comment remains applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Um, I just checked, and there appears to be a much simpler solution.

```
>>> a = [[42, 45], [45, 48], [48, 51], [0, 4], [4, 8]]
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[[0, 4], [4, 8], [42, 45], [45, 48], [48, 51]]
```

EDIT:

If you want to also sort the sublists, you can use this:

```
>>> a = [[45, 42], [45, 48], [51, 48], [0, 4], [8, 4]] # swapped some values
>>> a = list(map(lambda pair : [min(pair), max(pair)], a))
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[[0, 4], [4, 8], [42, 45], [45, 48], [48, 51]]
```

The lambda expression creates a [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) (a function that's not tied to a name) that takes an input, `pair`, and returns a list containing first the smallest value, then the largest value.

The `map` function takes a function and an iterable  and applies the function to each element of the iterable. Doing this will generate a `map` object, however, so we turn it back into a list.

After that, the sublists should be sorted, so we can just call the `sort()` method like in the first example.

This is approximately the same as this code:

```
a = [[42, 45], [45, 48], [48, 51], [0, 4], [4, 8]]
newA = []
for element in a:
     newA.append([min(element), max(element)])
a = newA
a.sort()
```